# Java Regex: Why is in my sample not the longest resp. left match taken?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

**Test Case**

```
Pattern P1 = Pattern.compile(".*(<\\{([0-9A-Za-z_]+)\\}>).*");
Pattern P2 = Pattern.compile(".*(<\\{([0-9A-Za-z_]+)\\}>|\\{([0-9A-Za-z_]+)\\}).*");

String text = "a <{xyz}> b";

Matcher m = P1.matcher(text);
m.matches();
String g1 = m.group(1);
System.out.println(g1);

m = P2.matcher(text);
m.matches();
g1 = m.group(1);
System.out.println(g1);
```

**Output**

```
<{xyz}>
{xyz}
```

**Question**

I would have expected, that for P2 the output would also be `<{xyz}>` because

- it is the first rule in the OR
- the match `<{xyz}>` is longer than `{xyz}`

Guess I have missed something but can't figure out what. So my goal would be that also for the pattern with the OR condition the result is `<{xyz}>`.

The verbal goal is like:
Match either something within `<{...}>` OR `{...}` but if the input is with `<>`, then take this as the preferred one.

The only solution which currently comes into my mind is to split P2 in two regular expressions, and first apply the input to that one with the `<>` and if this does not match try the other one without the `<>`. But I would be curious how this would work with just one regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is greedy `.*` at the start of your 2nd regex that is matching longest match before allowing pattern in `(...)`.

Change it to non-greedy one:

```
.*?(<\{([0-9A-Za-z_]+)\}>|\{([0-9A-Za-z_]+)\}).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK0qJ8/1)